# Refacoring data output for a node chart

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clean the data refactor for this node chart.

so I want the input data to be two arrays that have similar label/value/item arrangement.

```
    var data = [{
        "id": 11929,
        "label": "Rihanna",
        "image": "https://i.insider.com/5c61c45deb3ce845b033b4f5?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp",
        "items": [{
            "id": 991,
            "label": "Gardening",
            "value": 10
          },
          {
            "id": 998,
            "label": "Feng Shui",
            "value": 10
          },
          {
            "id": 992,
            "label": "Bowling",
            "value": 15
          },
          {
            "id": 994,
            "label": "Sculpting",
            "value": 35
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 12329,
        "label": "Brody",
        "image": "https://media1.popsugar-assets.com/files/thumbor/4UYUg9UKWqqhaFfElFDU9bKMRgQ/356x1145:1857x2646/fit-in/500x500/filters:format_auto-!!-:strip_icc-!!-/2019/09/04/970/n/1922398/cc3fa7b15d70381d55bd82.88203803_/i/Brad-Pitt.jpg",
        "items": [{
            "id": 996,
            "label": "Bodybuilding",
            "value": 10
          },
          {
            "id": 798,
            "label": "Comics",
            "value": 10
          },
          {
            "id": 992,
            "label": "Bowling",
            "value": 15
          },
          {
            "id": 994,
            "label": "Sculpting",
            "value": 35
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

which then gets refactored to create this node/link tree.

```
    var data1 = {
      "nodes": [{
          "id": "-parent-11929-rihanna"
        }, {
          "id": "-parent-12329-brody"
        }, {
          "id": "991-gardening"
        }, {
          "id": "998-feng-shui"
        }, {
          "id": "992-bowling"
        }, {
          "id": "994-sculpting"
        }, {
          "id": "996-bodybuilding"
        }, {
          "id": "798-comics"
        },
      ],
      "links": [{
        "source": "-parent-11929-rihanna",
        "target": "991-gardening"
      }, {
        "source": "-parent-11929-rihanna",
        "target": "998-feng-shui"
      }, {
        "source": "-parent-11929-rihanna",
        "target": "992-bowling"
      }, {
        "source": "-parent-11929-rihanna",
        "target": "994-sculpting"
      }, {
        "source": "-parent-12329-brody",
        "target": "996-bodybuilding"
      }, {
        "source": "-parent-12329-brody",
        "target": "798-comics"
      }, {
        "source": "-parent-12329-brody",
        "target": "992-bowling"
      }, {
        "source": "-parent-12329-brody",
        "target": "994-sculpting"
      }]
    }
```

the current function for this I've started is here.
current jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pvnmcw3z/

```
    function refactored(data) {
      var nodes = [];
      nodes.push({
        "id": "-parent-11929-rihanna"
      });


      var links = [];
      links.push({
        "source": "-parent-12329-brody",
        "target": "798-comics"
      });

      var datax = {
        "nodes": nodes,
        "links": links
      }


      return datax;
    }

    var datax = refactored(data);
            console.log("datax", datax);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pvnmcw3z/1/  -- this creates the nodes -- but still has duplicates appearing --

Comment: latest version -- creates the links -- https://jsfiddle.net/pvnmcw3z/2/

Comment: this creates UNIQUE nodes - https://jsfiddle.net/pvnmcw3z/4/

Comment: I've created a refactor function to take the input data and make nodes/links from it - https://jsfiddle.net/batv60je/4/